# sample issue for the latest google voice api (Oct 2016)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-speech

please have mercy on a noob question.

I was going over the google voice api tutorial with python (https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/rest-tutorial) and have done the following:

1. set up a Cloud Speed API project on Google Console
2. Generated / saved google service credential json file
3. Installed google-api-python-client==1.5.4 and switched to python 3.5 env
4. Saved transcribe.py code from tutorial
5. Saved sample audio.raw file from tutorial
6. Authenticated by executing:

> $ export
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=my_service_account.json

and

> $ export GCLOUD_PROJECT=my_project_id

Now when I run

> $ python tutorial.py audio.raw

I get the following tracebacks.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tutorial.py", line 23,
> in <module>
>     from googleapiclient import discovery   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py",
> line 73, in <module>
>     from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py",
> line 45, in <module>
>     from oauth2client import crypt   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py",
> line 45, in <module>
>     from oauth2client import _openssl_crypt   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/_openssl_crypt.py",
> line 16, in <module>
>     from OpenSSL import crypto   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py",
> line 8, in <module>
>     from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py",
> line 12, in <module>
>     from OpenSSL._util import (   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py",
> line 6, in <module>
>     from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding   File
> "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py",
> line 234, in <module>
>     Binding.init_static_locks()   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py",
> line 180, in init_static_locks
>     cls._ensure_ffi_initialized()   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py",
> line 167, in _ensure_ffi_initialized
>     cls.lib = build_conditional_library(lib, CONDITIONAL_NAMES)   File "/Users/bonjuice/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py",
> line 104, in build_conditional_library
>     if not getattr(lib, condition): AttributeError: cffi library '_openssl' has no function, constant or global variable named
> 'Cryptography_HAS_RSA_OAEP_MD'
```

I did some searching on "Cryptography_HAS_RSA_OAEP_MD" but to no avail. Could someone please point me to where I got wrong? Thanks!